# Can I pass an object's reference from one activity to another in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using Intent Service in my program. In the Intent Service, I have a timer task thread which runs every 15 mins. Since it runs ina new thread, there is no way to stop it other than from inside the thread itself, which is not possible in my situation. So, I want to be able to pass a reference of the timer object from the initial activity to the Intent Service. And using that refernce, can I start or stop the timertask?
 How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the Intent Service, I have a timer task thread which runs every 15 mins.

That is a very bad idea.

First, it will not work. An `IntentService` shuts down as soon as `onHandleIntent()` returns. What you are really doing is *leaking* a thread.

Second, it requires this `Service` to stay in memory all of the time, which is an anti-pattern in Android.

Please use `AlarmManager` to send commands to your `IntentService` every 15 minutes, and get rid of your timer task.

And, by doing this, you no longer have to worry about passing this sort of object around between an activity and a service.

Comment: Will AlarmManager work even when the application itself is closed. And if the application itself is closed, will the alarm manager be able to invoke the background service every 15 mins.

Comment: @Ashwin: "Will AlarmManager work even when the application itself is closed." -- for most conventional definitions of "closed", yes. "And if the application itself is closed, will the alarm manager be able to invoke the background service every 15 mins." -- that would appear to be the same question.